# Finiteness in Nisnevich covering

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Supppse, $X$ is a smooth finite type scheme over a field $k$. Suppse $\{U_{\alpha} \to X\}_{\alpha \in I}$ (I need not be a finite set) is a family of morphisms to $X$ which is a Nisnevich covering of $X$. Then there are finitely many $\alpha_1,..,\alpha_n \in I$ such that $\{U_{\alpha_i} \to X\}_{1\leq i \leq n}$ is a Nisnevich covering.

Comment: Smooth of finite type over a field is a too strong condition, being noetherian is already enough.

Comment: can you please sketch the proof..

Comment: It would behoove you to add the definition on Nisnevich covering to your post with an [edit]. Right now this is a little low on context and that would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comment, being noetherian is already sufficient, so let $X$ be a noetherian scheme and $\left \{f_i \colon U_i \longrightarrow X \right \}$ be a Nisnevich covering, that is, $f_i$ are 'etale and $f_i$ are jointly surjective and for each $x \in X$, there exists some $i$ and $y \in U_i$ with $f(y) = x$ and $k(y) = k(x)$. We simply say that we can lift $x$ to $U$. Your problem is to prove that any Nisnevich covering admits a finite subcovering. It is done by noetherian induction and the following observation:

**Lemma**. *Let $f \colon U \longrightarrow X$ be a morphism of finite type. Assume that $u \in U, x \in X$ be points such that $f(u) = x$ and $k(x) = k(u)$. Then there exists an open neighborhood of $x$ in $\overline{\left \{x \right \}}$ in which any point has the same property*.

*Proof*. Indeed, we can consider the induced morphism (of finite type) $f \colon \overline{\left \{y \right \}} \longrightarrow \overline{\left \{x \right \}}$ of integral schemes. It induces an isomorphism of function fields, so it must be an isomorphism over some open subscheme of $\overline{\left \{x \right \}}$.

Let's come back to the problem. Let $P$ be the following property of proper closed subschemes of $X$: *$Z \subset X$ closed has $P$ if and only if any Nisnevich covering of $Z$ admits a finite subcovering*. Under this hypothesis, we have to prove that $X$ itself has $P$. Since $X$ is notherian, it has finitely many irreducible components so we can list their generic points as $x_1,...,x_n$. Let $f_{i_1}\colon U_{i_1} \longrightarrow X,..., f_{i_n}\colon U_{i_n} \longrightarrow X$ be morphisms in the given covering so $x_1,...,x_n$ are lifted to $U_{i_1},...,U_{i_n}$. By the lemma above, there exist open neighborhoods $V_{i_j}$ of $x_j$ in $\overline{\left \{x_j \right \}}$ such that each point in $V_{i_j}$ can be lifted to $U_{i_j}$. Define $Z = X \setminus (\bigcup_{j=1}^n V_{i_j})$, clearly $Z$ is a proper closed subset of $X$ and by the induction hypothesis, $Z$ can be covered by a finitely number of $f_i \colon U_i \longrightarrow X$, indexed by $J$. The set $f_i \colon U_i \longrightarrow X$ with $i \in J \cup \left \{i_1,...,i_n \right \}$ gives us the desired finite covering.

To finish, we consider the following set
$$S = \left \{Z \subset X \ \text{closed such that} \ Z \ \text{does not have} \ P \right \}.$$
If $S$ is nonempty, say $Z_1 \subset X$ so that $Z_1$ does not have $P$. By the proof above, there exists some proper closed subset $Z_2 \subset Z_1$ such that $Z_2$ does not have $P$ (otherwise $Z_1$ itself has $P$). Iterate this process, we see that there exists an infinite chain of closed subsets of $X$ that is not stationary, which contradicts the notherian property of $X$.